# How to get an SMTP response using Javamail

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm using Javamail to connect to an AWS email service; I've tested that I can receive emails using this code, but I would also like to get a response with data about the sent email, such as the Message ID, which AWS uses to uniquely identify a message.

I'm using MimeMessage to create an email and I am sending it with this code within a try catch block:

```
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients)
```

This code just fires off an email to the AWS server and I can't get any metadata back. Is there a way to listen for a response to see if the message was successful so I can retrieve the Message ID?

Comment: That isn't part of the SMTP spec, so no - the server doesn't send that information to the transmitter.

Comment: Indeed. Have you checked with this message metadata is ever returned to the sender? Ordinary SMTP is not very verbose but, for all I know, Amazon might have some extension. If it does, the SMTP protocol is so simple that it's not hugely difficult just to send a message using Java sockets. JavaMail defines a `TransportListener`, but I doubt it will capture data that isn't generic stuff in SMTP.

Comment: Yes the sent email contains the metadata that I need. Thanks all, I will look into using the API email alternative that AWS provides.

Comment: Often the SMTP protocol conversation will include clues about what the message id is.  Apparently https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html will allow a Logger to be configured, maybe this could be queried to get message ids?  Not sure what use those ids would be though!  I've (many many years ago and in perl) written a email handling system that tried to track all the emails attempted sending by id.  It had to parse the logs and all kinds of stuff to make it work.  Doubt that you could do this on AWS

Answer (score 0):

If the sendMessage method returns, the server accepted the message.  Note that [that doesn't necessarily mean it will be delivered to the recipient](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#badaddr), however.  But at that point you can use the [getMessageID](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getMessageID--) method to retrieve the message ID.

If the send method throws an exception, the server refused to accept the message for some reason and it won't be sent.

Comment: This does work, but I've looked at the Message ID generated by AWS and it's different. So I need to find a way to get this ID instead. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you talking about the Message-ID header in the message that the recipient gets?  If AWS is rewriting the Message-ID header while sending the message which it really shouldn't do), I'm not sure how to get that information.  If it does include that information in the SMTP response code, it's possible to monitor the SMTP responses using JavaMail.  Can you post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) showing the SMTP response with the Message-ID?

Answer (score 0):

add properties `mail.smtp.reportsuccess` and `mail.smtp.sendpartial` to you java Mail Properties, you will get `SMTPAddressSucceededException` if send email success or `SMTPAddressFailedException` in fail.

[javamail doc](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html)